# C Program That Counts Even Integers from a Set of 5 Integers

Tags: c, if-statement, count, sum, int

I am trying to write a C program where the user enters five different integers and determines the amount of even integers from the input of those five integers. Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, sum;

//user enters 5 integers

    printf("Enter five different positive integers: \n");

//program scans for user input

    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5);

//if statement to determine what integers are even

    if(((n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)%2)==0)

//sum of even integers

        sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;

//program prints sum of even integers

        printf("There are %d even integers in the input. \n", sum); 

//program prints if there are no even integers for the inputs

    else

        printf("There are no even integers in the input. \n");

    return(0);
}
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Try using an array and loops.    In all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is not stated as clearly as needed:

- Do you want to sum all even integers an ignore odd integers typed?
- Do you want all integers to be even and refuse the input if it contains none?

Either way, your program fails for multiple reasons:

- `if(((n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)%2)==0)` does nothing useful: it only checks if the last integer is even. You could check if all integers are even with this

  ```
   if ((n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5) % 2) == 0)
  ```
- You did not use braces to group the instructions in the `if` body.  Unlike Python, indentation play no role in C, you must use braces (`{` and `}`) around multiple instructions to form a block after `if`, `else`, `while`, `for` etc.

Here is a modified version of your code that ignores the odd numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) {
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, sum, count;

    // user enters 5 integers
    printf("Enter five different positive integers:\n");

    // program scans for user input

    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5) != 5) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // for each integer, add it if it is even

    count = 0;
    sum = 0;

    if (n1 % 2 == 0) {
        sum += n1;
        count++;
    }
    if (n2 % 2 == 0) {
        sum += n2;
        count++;
    }
    if (n3 % 2 == 0) {
        sum += n3;
        count++;
    }
    if (n4 % 2 == 0) {
        sum += n4;
        count++;
    }
    if (n5 % 2 == 0) {
        sum += n5;
        count++;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        printf("There are %d even integers in the input, their sum is %d.\n",
               count, sum); 
    } else {
        //program prints if there are no even integers for the inputs
        printf("There are no even integers in the input.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using some more advanced knowledge of C, you could *simplify* the code into this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) {
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, sum, count;

    printf("Enter five different positive integers:\n");
    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5) != 5) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // use the low order bit to test oddness
    count = 5 - ((n1 & 1) + (n2 & 1) + (n3 & 1) + (n4 & 1) + (n5 & 1));
    sum = n1 * !(n1 & 1) + n2 * !(n2 & 1) + n3 * !(n3 & 1) +
          n4 * !(n4 & 1) + n4 * !(n4 & 1);

    if (count > 0) {
        printf("There are %d even integers in the input, their sum is %d.\n",
               count, sum); 
    } else {
        printf("There are no even integers in the input.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it is actually more complicated, less readable and not provably more efficient.

The real improvement would be to use a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) {
    int i, n, sum = 0, count = 0;

    printf("Enter five different positive integers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d, &n) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            sum += n;
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        printf("There are %d even integers in the input, their sum is %d.\n",
               count, sum); 
    } else {
        printf("There are no even integers in the input.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple test of even numbers is divide by 2 and test for a 0 remainder

```
   if (  N % 2 == 0 ) {  // This is even, inc your even counter here}
```

just use a for loop and step thru adding up all that prove even

this works for float or int just fine

Answer (score 0):

(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5) is a sequence of expressions, separated by commas, which evaluates to the last expression, so this:

```
//if statement to determine what integers are even
if(((n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)%2)==0)
```

only determines the divisibility of `n5`

You can use an array:

```
int n[5];
```

And then, in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if ((n[i] % 2) == 0) {
        sum += n[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ques**. What you want to do?

**Ans.**  You want to write a C program That **Counts Even Integers from a Set of 5 Integers**.   that gives ouput as **no. of even integers** in the set of 5 integers.

I think you don't have learn the concept of array. Array make this problem to solve easily. but, don't worry I understand you according to you ques. 
but,
    **It's your task to learn what is array why and when we use it ?**

-----------------xxx--------xxx----------xxx-----------xxx-----------------------------------------------------------------------

**Requirements are:**

1. 5 variable (i.e. num) that stores the values given by user
2. A variable i.e. count that counts the no. of even no's. it's initializes with 0 because initially no even no's are there before input is given.

-----------------xxx--------xxx----------xxx-----------xxx----------------------------------------------------------------------

1 more problem in your code :-

```
if(((n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)%2)==0) //it only check for n5 because comma operator seperates the values and gives only last value(i.e. n5) for computaion.
```

**Solution:-**

```
#include <stdio.h> 

    int main()
    {
        int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, count=0;     //var count works as a counter variable and it's value will update by 1 when any even no. encounters.


  printf("Enter five different positive integers: \n");

  scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5);


   if(n1%2==0)
    {
      count=count+1;       //now, count is set by 1 if the first input(n1) found even
    }


    if(n2%2==0)
    {
      count=count+1;       //now, count is set by 2 if the second input(n2) found even
    }


    if(n3%2==0)
    {
      count=count+1;       //now, count is set by 3 if the third input(n3) found even
    }

    if(n4%2==0)
    {
      count=count+1;       //now, count is set by 4 if the fourth input(n4) found even
    }


    if(n5%2==0)
    {
      count=count+1;       //now, count is set by 5 if the fifth input(n5) found even
    }




            printf("There are %d even integers in the input. \n", count); //count holds no. of even integers enconteres among 5 

//if count prints 0 it indicates no even no occured.
```

**you have to write same code using array and using loop. it's becomes your code small and fast to execute :)**

Comment: if you like my way to sollve your problem, you may do vote to my ans or accept the answer. ;)